# always on top window or bring a window to top when there are other topmost windows

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

I have 2 HWND_TOPMOST windows, among which I wanted to maintain 1 window always on top for sometime, is there a way we can bring a window to the top of the other topmost windows ?

I just tried below option, just catch when my window goes out of focus by other window & trying to take it to foreground but it is not working at all.

```
case WM_KILLFOCUS:
{
  //tried below all options 
    ::BringWindowToTop(hWnd):  
    ::SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    ::SetFocus(hWnd);
    ::SetActiveWindow(hWnd);
}
```

please do suggest some way to achieve this..

Comment: What if two windows wanted to do this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  yes, there will be a conflict. but at least it is not the case in my application.

Comment: I don't mean within your application. What about my program that wants to be on top of your program. In my view, mine is more important and will be on top of yours. OK?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  I got your point.. but but i am looking if there is a possibility for this not exactly with the code I have written may be diff way, that is what I wanted to know.

Comment: down voterrr... any comments, any solution, any idea ??

Comment: See [Owned Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no solution for this. You should read the rationale and explanation from the Windows developer, Raymond Chen, here:

[How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253)